# Validating Checkboxes - Not detecting it's checked

Tags: javascript, validation, checkbox

I've been struggling over this all day. All the other validation works fine except for the check boxes. It seems to validate it but doesn't detect when things are checked. Meaning, I'll check a box and it'll still say to enter in a contact time, no matter what box I check. Please help!!

Its just the one for selecting the best time to contact you that's acting up.

Here's my check boxes:

```
<input id="best_contact_time" name="best_contact_time" value="Morning 7-12" class="inputCheckbox" type="checkbox">Morning (7-12)<br>
<input id="best_contact_time" name="best_contact_time" value="Afternoon 12-5" class="inputCheckbox" type="checkbox">Afternoon (12-5)<br>
<input id="best_contact_time" name="best_contact_time" value="Evening 5-9" class="inputCheckbox" type="checkbox">Evening (5-9)<br>
```

And my validation code:

```
    function submitme() {
    // Validate required fields
    if (get_element('lastname').value == '') {
        alert('Please enter your last name');
        return false;
    }
    if (get_element('first_name').value == '') {
        alert('Please enter your first name');
        return false;
    }
    if (get_element('phone').value == '') {
        alert('Please enter a phone number');
        return false;
    }

    if (get_element('email').value == '') {
        alert('Please enter an email address');
        return false;
    }

    var ischecked = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < document.rental.best_contact_time.length; i++) {
            var e = document.rental.best_contact_time;
            if (e.checked == true)
            { ischecked = 1; }
        }
        if (ischecked == 0) {
            alert('Please enter the best time to contact you');
            return false;
        }



    if (get_element('approximate_start_date').value == '') {
        alert('Please enter an approximate start date');
        return false;

    }



    document.forms[0].submit();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: an ID(`best_contact_time`) should be unique and not be the same on all three inputs

Comment: Did you mean to write document.rental.best_contact_time[i]?

Answer (score 2):

Since you have multiple elements with the same name, `document.rental.best_contact_time` will be a **NodeList** not an HTMLElementNode.

You would need to loop through the list (treat it like an array) and check each one in turn.

Comment: aka: `var e = document.rental.best_contact_time[i];`  Also e is a bad variable name for an object, it is normally used for events or exceptions.